# Can't save system image using Windows 7 Backup onto D: drive

Tags: windows-10, windows-backup

I have Windows 10 installed on a C: drive, and D: on a separate physical drive.

When I go into Backup & Restore (Windows 7) > Change Settings, I see:

[image]

> A system image cannot be saved on this location. More information > "A
> system image cannot be saved on a drive that your computer boots from
> or that Windows is installed on".

My computer neither boots from D: nor has Windows installed on D.

How can I get past this message and save a system image on D:?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use a physically external drive for this process to work.

Comment: Or make a complete image, not just System files, using third-party software, such as Macrium Reflect Free. If there's enough room on D:, then you can make a *complete* backup there.